# Prove or disprove either t(n) ∈ O(g(n)), or t(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)), or both

Tags: algorithm, big-o, proof

Does anyone know how to prove or disapprove that:

```
For any two nonnegative functions t(n) and g(n) defined on the set of nonnegative
integers, either t(n) ∈ O(g(n)), or t(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)), or both.
```

I've found the answer of this question on [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/7-prove-following-assertions-using-definitions-notations-volved-disprove-giving-specific-c-q36920884), but the answer doesn't make sense for me since it just simply approved that t(n) = g(n) when n=1. However, I think it's wrong because the assertion looks like still True since  it said "both", which includes the case t(n) = g(n) .

Hope someone could tell me this assertion is true and false with proof.

Comment: This does not seem a question about programming. Why not ask on https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: (1) We can not access that Chegg Article without registration : Better to include all Details in your Post (2) It will suit **CompSci OR Math Stack Exchange** : there is no Programming Issue here.

Comment: The link to the answer is not public. So we cannot comment on your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

It's false. For example f(n)=1 if n is a multiple of 3, and n otherwise. Let g(n)=1 if n is a multiple of 2, and n otherwise.

f is neither bound above nor below by any constant multiple of g.

Comment: Thank you so much, you explained this so clearly!!